# How to apply padding for Base64

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography

I have following code that works fine when I use a four letter word as input, E.g. “Test”. When the input is not a multiple of 4, it fails E.g. “MyTest”.

> Eexception: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is it guaranteed that the encrypted result will be always compatible to a Unicode string (without any loss). If yes I can use UTF encoding instead of Base64? [What's the difference between UTF8/UTF16 and Base64 in terms of encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866316/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-utf16-and-base64-in-terms-of-encoding)
2. How can add padding so that we get correct result (after decryption) even if the input is not a multiple of 4?

**MAIN PRGORAM**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string valid128BitString = "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==";
        string inputValue = "MyTest";
        string keyValue = valid128BitString;


        byte[] byteValForString = Convert.FromBase64String(inputValue);
        EncryptResult result = Aes128Utility.EncryptData(byteValForString, keyValue);
        EncryptResult encyptedValue = new EncryptResult();
        string resultingIV = "4uy34C9sqOC9rbV4GD8jrA==";
        if (String.Equals(resultingIV,result.IV))
        {
            int x = 0;
        }

        encyptedValue.IV = resultingIV;
        encyptedValue.EncryptedMsg = result.EncryptedMsg;

        string finalResult = Convert.ToBase64String(Aes128Utility.DecryptData(encyptedValue, keyValue));
        Console.WriteLine(finalResult);

        if (String.Equals(inputValue, finalResult))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Differ");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**AES Crypto UTILITY**

```
public static class Aes128Utility
{
    private static byte[] key;

    public static EncryptResult EncryptData(byte[] rawData, string strKey)
    {
        EncryptResult result = null;
        if (key == null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strKey))
            {
                key = Convert.FromBase64String((strKey));
                result = Encrypt(rawData);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result = Encrypt(rawData);
        }

        return result; 

    }

    public static byte[] DecryptData(EncryptResult encryptResult, string strKey)
    {
        byte[] origData = null;
        if (key == null)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strKey))
            {
                key = Convert.FromBase64String(strKey);
                origData = Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptResult.EncryptedMsg), Convert.FromBase64String(encryptResult.IV));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            origData = Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptResult.EncryptedMsg), Convert.FromBase64String(encryptResult.IV));
        }

        return origData; 
    }

    private static EncryptResult Encrypt(byte[] rawData)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesProvider.Key = key;
            aesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            aesProvider.IV = Convert.FromBase64String("4uy34C9sqOC9rbV4GD8jrA==");
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, aesProvider.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                encStream.Write(rawData, 0, rawData.Length);
                encStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                EncryptResult encResult = new EncryptResult();
                encResult.EncryptedMsg = Convert.ToBase64String(memStream.ToArray());
                encResult.IV = Convert.ToBase64String(aesProvider.IV);
                return encResult;
            }
        }
    }

    private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encryptedMsg, byte[] iv)
    {
        using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aesProvider = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            aesProvider.Key = key;
            aesProvider.IV = iv;
            aesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            aesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
            using (MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                CryptoStream decStream = new CryptoStream(memStream, aesProvider.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                decStream.Write(encryptedMsg, 0, encryptedMsg.Length);
                decStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return memStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

 }
```

**DTO**

```
public class EncryptResult
{
    public string EncryptedMsg { get; set; }
    public string IV { get; set; }
}
```

**REFERENCES**:

1. [How to create byte[] with length 16 using FromBase64String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954248/how-to-create-byte-with-length-16-using-frombase64string)
2. [Getting incorrect decryption value using AesCryptoServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14937707/getting-incorrect-decryption-value-using-aescryptoserviceprovider)

Comment: Why are your DTO's strings, is there a reason you can not transmit them as byte arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base64 is a way of representing binary values as text so that you do not conflict with common control codes like `\x0A` for newline or `\0` for a string terminator. It is **NOT** for turning **typed text** in to binary.

Here is how you should be passing the text in and getting it back out. You can replace `UTF8` with whatever encoding you want, but you will need to make sure the `Encoding.Whatever.GetBytes` is the same encoding as the `Encoding.Whatever.GetString`

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string valid128BitString = "AAECAwQFBgcICQoLDA0ODw==";
        string inputValue = "MyTest";
        string keyValue = valid128BitString;

        //Turns our text in to binary data
        byte[] byteValForString = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputValue);

        EncryptResult result = Aes128Utility.EncryptData(byteValForString, keyValue);
        EncryptResult encyptedValue = new EncryptResult();

        //(Snip)

        encyptedValue.IV = resultingIV;
        encyptedValue.EncryptedMsg = result.EncryptedMsg;

        string finalResult = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Aes128Utility.DecryptData(encyptedValue, keyValue));
        Console.WriteLine(finalResult);

        if (String.Equals(inputValue, finalResult))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Match");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Differ");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: When I convert the encrypted byte array to string, it is coming as a string with length of 24. That is fine. But what is the rationale behind the number 24?

Comment: Because to encode one byte it takes a 1 + 1/3 letters to encode it. So if you have a 1/3 or 2/3 remainder when you are done you need to pad it out with a special symbol that means "No data, just trying to round up to the next whole number". That symbol is normally `=`. See the [Wikipedia page on Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

If you are encrypting, then encoding Base64 for me doesn't add anything useful, instead it brings the problems you face.

As for the padding, a solution i have seen is to create a new byte[] that is indeed a multiple of 4 and copy the source byte[] to that new byte[].

So, something like this:

```
 if (rawdata.Length % 16 !=0)
 {
      newSource = new byte[source.Length + 16 - source.Length % 16];
      Array.Copy(source, newSource, source.Length);
 }
```